# Find width of li, based on text before creation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dom, razor

I am going to create a `<li>` tag, which will have an anchor inside it as `innerHTML`. I had text of the anchor based on that I want to calculate the width of the `<li>` going to be before creation. The HTML looks like below:

```
<li>---
    <a href="#">some text</a>-----------text ,which I know before hand
</li>------
```

As of my knowledge, if we need to know the width, the element must exists in the DOM.

Please let me know if anyone knows a workaround for this.....Mainly I have to calculate/get that in ASP.NET MVC Razor view, so obviously will be C#.....

Comment: It can be very difficult to get an exact measurement for a string of text on a client machine, so many different factors...OS, Browser, Fonts, zoom level, etc. If you really need to control layout with code, you may be better off shifting to the client and process the layout in JavaScript. Or look into using CSS to style things.

Comment: I know doing it some other way my requirement is to do the way i had mentioned above, as u said is it possible even it is difficult.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to calculate the width server-side? (If we understand the *why*, maybe we can assist)

Comment: I had changed my plan and handled it different way that worked for me, any ways the reason to try doing like above is, i am creating html from view dynamically and had a logic of width for displaying elements, so i want to know the width before hand.

Comment: This just breaks the MVC pattern. Controllers should not worry about view creation any more than of the controls in that view. This defeats the purpose of having MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the li as a temporary item, but hide it.  Then get the width, and then remove the temporary element.

Comment: I know that but i have to do that in the razor view not in js

Comment: Then there is no way for you to obtain the rendered width from a browser before rendering.  Maybe explain why you need to know the tag why you need the tag width ahead of time and someone might offer an alternative.